# Cannot capture CloudWatch logs of Lambda function after Terraform deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I ran terraform apply successfully, but none the console.log statements seem to be sent to CloudWatch. I followed this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75157142/9105207
I do see the CloudWatch log group created, but no log streams at all.

This is my code:

**CloudWatch file:**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "store_url_cloudwatch_log_group" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.store_url_lambda.function_name}"
  retention_in_days = 14

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    {
      Name  = "${var.project}-Store-URL-CloudWatch-Log-Group"
      Stack = "Backend"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "store_url_logging_policy" {
  name = "Store-url-logging-policy"

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource" : [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    {
      Name  = "${var.project}-Store-URL-Logging-Policy"
      Stack = "Backend"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "store_url_logging_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_store_url.id
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.store_url_logging_policy.arn
}
```

**Lambda function file**:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "store_url_lambda_assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda_store_url" {
  name               = "IAM-for-lambda-store-url"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.store_url_lambda_assume_role.json

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    {
      Name  = "${var.project}-Store-URL-Lambda-IAM-Role"
      Stack = "Backend"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "store_url_lambda" {
  function_name    = "store-url-lambda"
  role             = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_store_url.arn
  handler          = "index.handler"
  runtime          = "nodejs20.x"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_store_url_zip.output_base64sha256
  s3_bucket        = module.s3_store_url_lambda_bucket.s3_bucket_id
  s3_key           = aws_s3_object.store_url_lambda_s3_object.key
  depends_on       = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.store_url_cloudwatch_log_group]

  environment {
    variables = {
      S3_BUCKET = module.s3_store_url_lambda_bucket.s3_bucket_id
    }
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    {
      Name  = "${var.project}-Store-URL-Lambda-Function"
      Stack = "Backend"
    }
  )
}
```

I removed irrelevant blocks. In my Lambda function there are `console.log` statements. Example:

```js
import crypto from 'node:crypto';
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import RequestBody from './schemas/request-body';
import { doesObjectExist } from './utils/s3';
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const requestBody = event.body;
    console.log(`Request body is: ${requestBody}`);
```

Comment: Which region are you using?

Comment: @jellycsc `eu-central-1`

Comment: You are missing permissions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/access-logs.html

add these and retry the Lambda execution:

"Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:region:accountID:log-group:/aws/lambda/functionname:*"
            ]

Comment: @AnanthTirumanur I have these permissions on `Store-url-logging-policy` policy.

Comment: From the linked post: "Just adding the log group as a dependency to the lambda is not enough. You also have to attach the IAM policy to the lambda role.". Do you have the correct policy in "iam_for_lambda_store_url"? You also need to add the dependency: depends_on: [ aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example ] in your lambda.

Comment: @TsalTroser You can see I attach the policy to the role using the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` and also you can see I use the `depends_on` in the lambda function resource.

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice. Then this might be a permission issue. Have you tried to execute the lambda manually and see if there are errors in the console log? For the policy, the "Resource" should be an array and I think you also need "logs:CreateLogGroup". See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-identity-based-access-control-cwl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you don’t see your `console.log` statements output to CloudWatch does not mean that it does not have permissions. Maybe the function has yet to begin due to some prior error. Try to test it via the AWS console manually, and check whether some errors are emitted during this test.

Answer (score 0):

- Definitely check the permissions. The Lambda needs the same permissions as the AWS-managed policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.
- Also, there's a syntax error in your policy definition. I pasted your policy statement in the AWS policy editor and it showed a syntax error. This worked:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I used your policy and still, no logs show up. The log group is indeed created (as before), no the group is empty